# 2-2-2-4 AL SER Cable is short. What are my options?

Tags: wiring, subpanel

I have a 2-2-2-4 AL SER cable from my main panel, up, and in a straight line, perpendicular and through the overhead joists of my unfinished basement.  I am feeding it through the last joist into my attached garage, when I realize my SER cable is going to be about 6 feet short to make it to my new subpanel.  What are my options?

Comment: What actual load do you anticipate on the subpanel? That may affect available options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Pull the cable out and replace with a longer cable. If your original cable was a standard size (100' and you needed 106') then you might be able to return it for credit. If it was purchased by the foot, you won't get so much back.
2. Move the subpanel. Only practical if (a) you haven't started wiring up the subpanel and (b) the end of the cable is in a place that is *legal* for a subpanel - i.e., has a 30" x 36" space in front of it that can be kept clear.
3. Put in a big junction box and use Polaris connectors (or similar) to connect the wires to a 6' length of cable. This is trivially simple, but the Polaris connectors are not cheap.
4. Put in a disconnect box. That will take care of the hot wires (and neutral if you can get a 3-wire disconnect) just leaving ground and neutral to be spliced with polaris connectors inside the box. The problem is that disconnect boxes are dirt cheap up to 60A and then essentially go up to subpanel price *or higher*. And you can't just use a cheap 100A subpanel because subpanels need clear working space.

Comment: Disconnect as possibly cheaper splice. Very good.  Fair chance a 60A disconnect will take #2 wire, and then the breaker can be downsized to 60A easy peasy. However this won't allow ["bonkers speed" EV charging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w&t=1695s), bummer!

Comment: At least one disconnect I looked at would only go to 4 AWG, but there are others. You're right about the size - I'm assuming 2/2/2/4 = 90A. But it could be for a 60A panel and 2/2/2/4 = good price so why not.

Comment: At least Eaton (and maybe others) makes a 100A disconnect that can be found for under $100 as well.

Comment: @KMJ Can a disconnect be mounted to one of the overhead basement joists?

Comment: While junction boxes can be anywhere, as long as they are accessible, disconnects *might* have a "reach it easily" issue similar to GFCI. One of the pros may know the answer to that.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact How large a junction box would I need for the SER cable that isn't in conduit?  I do see that they make a 4 conductor Polaris.

Comment: Not sure how big a box. The box calculators I found all stop at 6 AWG. As far as Polaris, I am a little confused (since they are "read about it, never needed to use it" territory for me) - but I thought a 4-conductor Polaris is "connect 4 wires together", not "connect 4 pairs of wires". You are dealing with 4 pairs of wires (3 2 AWG and 1 4 AWG).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Good point, I will keep that in mind.  I am not familiar with Polaris connectors as well.

Comment: Polaris and Ilsco brand "multi tap connectors" are priced like they're special but there are other brands that are more reasonable. Morris #97116 is coming in around US$17 for two-port, insulated, 2/0-6 gauge. Four of those plus a box compares against the alternatives pretty well IMHO.

Comment: Penn-Union also makes a suitable one around $22/per from my local electrical supply shop. Four of those plus a box is probably the easiest way to go since you can put the J-box anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the info everyone.  I will look at cost/benefit of my alternatives.  At the end of the day, it may be best to chalk it up to experience and purchase the appropriate length.  I would take a hit of about $110.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'm having a difficult time finding SER cable by the foot.  I have the SER cable entering into a 1-1/2 inch PVC conduit, from the last joist of an unfinished basement, into an LB body, then 4 feet of conduit to the sub panel.  Can I add a proper sized junction box to the entrance point of the conduit and put the splices in this Jbox?  Splices would be left to right horizontal.  What kind of wire do I use for the wire that is spliced to the SER conductors that will be in the conduit?  Is THWN suitable?

Comment: manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact  I'm having a difficult time finding SER cable by the foot. I have the SER cable entering into a 1-1/2 inch PVC conduit, from the last joist of an unfinished basement, into an LB body, then 4 feet of conduit to the sub panel. Can I add a proper sized junction box to the entrance point of the conduit and put the splices in this Jbox? Splices would be left to right horizontal. What kind of wire do I use for the wire that is spliced to the SER conductors that will be in the conduit? Is THWN suitable?

Comment: If it's going into conduit, THWN should be perfectly fine. The SER cable doesn't need to be in conduit (but does need protection from damage below a certain height). I don't think it makes a difference THHN vs. THWN etc. as this is indoor use. Yes, a big junction box at the start of the conduit is all you need.

Comment: @user149104 make sure you're looking into *electrical supply houses*, family owned lumberyards which are not big-box stores, family hardware stores including ACE and HWI (which are cooperatives), and as a last resort there are online sellers who sell by the foot.  If you give up on the SER, remember you can always sell it on Craigslist/FB Marketplace.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact For the sizing of the pull box, NEC talks about the size of the raceways, but in my case, I will have the SER cable without a raceway entering the box, but the spliced THHN in 1-1/2" conduit leaving the box.  Do I size the box based on the 1-1/2" conduit (I calc 12 inch on the horizontal)?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Found what I need to do:  "When transposing cable size into raceway size in 314.28(A)(1) and (A)(2), the minimum metric designator (trade size) raceway required for the number and size of conductors in the cable shall be used".